# How to declare CSS values with fallbacks when a value is unsupported

Tags: javascript, css, fallback

I want to use

```
overflow: overlay
```

in chrome, but

```
overflow: scroll
```

in firefox. if I declare only the *overlay* value, then firefox would not scroll at all.
I know that overlay is not standard but this shall be perfectly irrelevant for now.

my question is, which is the best way to have each browser the value as described.

is it possible to have a fallback inside CSS alone? cannot think that there is, but maybe there is a trick.

if it requires javascript, how would I test for the availability of the overflow value?

Comment: Just write both declarations, the fallback declaration first. Browsers that support `overflow:overlay` will use that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just supply both of them, the browser will use the last recognized one.

Or you might want consider apply different styles for different browsers
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/create-browser-specific-css

Comment: The cascade specifies that "the last declaration in document order wins" (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#cascade-order). This means that the order is very important. It is not correct that the browser will ignore the invalid one. The browser will much more ignore ones he does not understand. This means that overflow: scroll followed by overflow:overlay does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly supply these values in CSS for the element.

You can also use classes to set this attribute. Have three individual classes that have these styles separately and use javascript to attach the classes with the first being the fallback styles.